# Why, when adding two or more identical objects to state in a row, they always generate the same key?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm learning React and i'm stuck on this problem. I've looked for answers but couldn't find why this exact thing was happening.

When i fill in a form and submit it, a new object gets added to the state. No matter how i generate random key (for example in code below i do it with date object and getTime method), when i add two or more identical objects to the state in a row (one exactly after the other), they always generate the same key, same with math.random and all other methods i've tried.

If i add one object and then change any data even a little bit and add another and then add the same as the first one, everything works perfectly. The only problem is when i try to add the same ones in a row.

By identical objects i mean that all their {key: value} pairs contain the same data and they have the same keys.

This is how my state objects like like:

```
state = {
    dmd: [
      {name: 'dmd', age: 69, rich: 'yes', id: 1},
      {name: 'lk', age: 19, rich: 'true', id: 2},
      {name: 'tm', age: 83, rich: 'aye', id: 3}
    ]
  }
```

Note that when i have this initial state already hard coded, when i add a new object that's the same as the 3rd one, the error doesn't occur. It's just when creating new ones.

newDmd object that is passed to addDmd method would not have id at first and would look like this:

```
{name: 'john', age: 22, rich: 'yes'}
```

Method used to change state:

```
  addDmd = (newDmd) => {
    newDmd.id = new Date().getTime();
    let newArray = [...this.state.dmd, newDmd];
    this.setState({
      dmd: newArray
    });
  }
```

The image below is to show you when the keys become the same (my key is 'id'). You can see that on the last 3 additions, the key is the same, starting to repeat after the second one:

I don't have enough reputation points to post an image, so here's a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXXxk.png

I would like to know:

1. Why this happens
2. How to fix this
3. Best practices regarding changing state and generating unique keys

Edit:
Adding code from where addDmd method is called.

```
class AddDmd extends Component {
    state = {
        name: null,
        age: null,
        rich: null
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addDmd(this.state);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    <label htmlFor="age">Age:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="age" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    <label htmlFor="rich">rich?:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="rich" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    <button>Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Edit 2: added full code of class where addDmd method resides.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    dmd: [
      {name: 'dmd', age: 69, rich: 'yes', id: 1},
      {name: 'lk', age: 19, rich: 'true', id: 2},
      {name: 'tm', age: 83, rich: 'aye', id: 3}
    ]
  }

  addDmd = (newDmd) => {
    newDmd.id = new Date().getTime();
    let newArray = [...this.state.dmd, newDmd];
    this.setState({
      dmd: newArray
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <AddDmd addDmd={this.addDmd} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create an example of your code on sandbox or any other online editor?

Comment: Show how `addDmd` is getting used. My best guess is that its being passed the same object reference and the `id` is being overwritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your issue is related to accidental mutation of nested objects by reference.

**1. Why this happens:**

I can only speculate for now. If you want to share the usage of `addDmd` I can confirm. I believe `newDmd` is populated from a previous entry. Which means doing `newDmd.id =`  will mutate both objects in state.

You can confirm this yourself by checking the `id` each time a new entry is added. The new `id` should be different since its based on time, but watch and see if the previous entries are changing along with it.

**2. How to fix it:**

Change your function to this so that it makes deep copies of the state:

```js
addDmd = (newDmd) => {
  newDmd.id = new Date().getTime();
  let newArray = [...this.state.dmd.map(nestedObj => ({...nestedObj})), newDmd];
  this.setState({
    dmd: newArray
  });
}
```

**3. Best practices:**

As far as I can tell your method of generating unique keys should work fine. The best practice I would recommend is to make sure you make deep copies of state when necessary.

### Update

I was pretty close. The issue is you're passing `this.state` directly to `addDmd`. `this.state` gets a new object reference every time the component re-renders, but if you don't change any values in the form and submit again - it doesn't need to re-render. This means you pass `addDmd` the same object reference.

Simple fix:

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.addDmd({...this.state}); // Create new object out of state
}
```

Now you can submit the same form as many times as you want and it will always submit a new object reference and will not mutate the previous submission.

Comment: I added my code from where i call addDmd method at the end of my post. It would be great if you could help me.

Comment: @Silenc3 Yes, I added the specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Why this happens ?**
I totally agree with the reason @Brian Thompsan mentioned.

Also, I have create a example code for your use-case where I am adding a same item with different ids (created using date/time) on the button click. Its working fine and here is the code.

```
import React from "react";
import Listbox from "./listBox";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dmd: [
        { name: "dmd", age: 69, rich: "yes", id: 1 },
        { name: "lk", age: 19, rich: "true", id: 2 },
        { name: "tm", age: 83, rich: "aye", id: 3 }
      ]
    };
  }
  addDmd = () => {
    const newId = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(newId);
    let newArray = [
      ...this.state.dmd,
      { id: newId, name: "new name", age: "new age" }
    ];
    this.setState({
      dmd: newArray
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <input type="button" onClick={this.addDmd} />
        {this.state.dmd.map(item => (
          <div>
            id: {item.id} name:: {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```